Find values that make function lebesgue integrable
For which exponents $p,q,r \in \mathbb{R}$ is a function $$ \frac{1}{|x_1|^p+|x_2|^q+|x_3|^r} $$integrable
I) in a neighborhood of $0$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$?
II) at infinity?
I tried to solve I) first, but the results were I integral in unit ball center at $(0,0,0)$. If one of $p,q,r \le 0$. I can bound the given function with $1$. which makes the function integrable, so I consider case $p,q,r>0$, let $a = \min\{p,q,r\}$, then I get lower bound of the function is $\frac{1}{|x_1|^a+|x_2|^a+|x_3|^a} \ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{(|x_1|^2+|x_2|^2+|x_3|^2)^{a}}}$ and change coordinate to Spherical coordinate, I got $a < 3$ that make the integral convergence. I claim that $0<p,q,r <3$ make the integral convergence, but I still cannot prove it.
